# How to update a sitemap.xml

Tags: spring-boot, static, sitemap

I want to update my sitemap.xml.

I created a method which generates me, for the moment in a temporary folder( in windows), a sitemap.xml.

I wish to do

```
File file = new File (???)
```

but how to create a file directly in the static of spring boot?
To make it accessible https: //example/siemap.xml

Is possible ?

Or do I have to create an external classpath?

thank you